# ¿Cómo importar módulos en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un código que no es mío lo encontré en Internet y es lo que necesito, pero al parecer esta para ejecutarse en NodeJS, algo que no sé, quisiera ver si se puede pasar a JavaScript que pueda ejecutar en un Navegador, el primer problema que tengo es importar un modulo o carpeta; ¿Cómo se hace en un Navegador con JavaScript esta acción?

Código:

```
var request = require("request");


   var cheerio = require("cheerio");
    var TARGET  = "http://www.votoinformado.pe/voto/miembro_mesa.aspx";


    function getPage(dni , callback) {

        var data = {
            "__EVENTTARGET" : "btnCongrDNI" ,
            "__EVENTARGUMENT" : "" ,
            "__VIEWSTATE" : "zcBdANVv3exPVBq2FCzvOHX9h711Am07uOAIKAjl0Ql78kOEsoinh5xFeSiCbeCNv5HiI/8cDr+atRB0T

6vVJY/TS7vgkxSl7EhaRD+VHRWuen4dwV+vkjN+nTQVORIEFTic9A==" ,
            "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" : "A8656B09" ,
            "__EVENTVALIDATION" : "QdJQGNSuWQL8PBg1OxKT1WE6ku/Ni943XmKPdYzs+/etXwXFwQDG82oViGNviBgmou//cqrIY3o6WYpuh2j2z03CaCtL53OX9BGhjecFYmDdkB/tjFSSJtTHFlKgfNVlkdNSxmx3WAJvlws7VhgtDuNqdZNPbNaVHA6Ed4RnX9RNb7fu" ,
        "txtCongrDNI" : dni
};

request.post(TARGET , { form : data } , function (err , response , body) {
    if ( err ) {
        return callback(err);
    } else {
        return callback(null , body);
    }
});
}

function parse(html , cb) {
    try {
        var $      = cheerio.load(html);
        var table  = $("table.tblRespuesta");
        var result = {};

        result.dni            = table.find("#lblDNI").text();
        result.nombres        = table.find("#lblNombres").text();
        result.miembro_mesa   = table.find("#lblDNI").text();
        result.ubicacion      = table.find("#lblUbicacion").text();
        result.mesa_sufragio  = table.find("#lblMesa").text();
        result.local_votacion = table.find("#LblLocal").text();
        result.direccion      = table.find("#lblDireccion").text();

        return cb(null , result);
    } catch ( err ) {
        return cb(err);
    }
}


getPage("06477277" , function (err , html) {
    parse(html , function (err , data) {
        if ( err ) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

El código de node es javascript, no existe código node y código javascript como lenguajes separados. Node es una plataforma que crea un entorno para usar javascript en el contexto del servidor pero sigue siendo javascript. Si pegas ese código en un script que ejecutes en el navegador no funcionará pero viendo el script lo que hace es una petición http a esta url: http://www.votoinformado.pe/voto/miembro_mesa.aspx

Y hace una serie de operaciones con el resultado de esa petición.

Lo que te puede ser útil es cambiar request por [browser-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-request) que te permite usar ese módulo o librería desde un navegador, es decir, "javascript normal".

Ahí viene la documentación de cómo usarlo. Quizá necesites repasar javascript para que comprendas del todo.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque tienes un poco confundidos tus conceptos debes de tener en cuenta que importar módulos JavaScript en NodeJS es con el fin de que estén disponibles en el contexto para su uso, en un Navegador sólo debes añadir la referencia de la librería a través de la etiqueta de HTML `<script />`.

Lo que necesitas referente al módulo de `request` lo podrías hacer haciendo uso de JQuery `$.post()` [en el sitio de W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp) podes encontrar detalles de JQuery AJAX y ejemplos de uso para lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Como dicen las demas respuesta nodejs es javscript, la diferencia es como importan los modulos, nodejs usa `commonjs`, que no lo puedes hacer desde el browser, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es migrar el codigo e incluir request desde un `<script>` tag o, tambien puedes usar algunas de las herramientas que vienen para ello, hay unas cuantas como webpack, browserify ...

Te dejo el link de https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify browserify, que supongo que es una de las mas simples, que como dice convierte los modulos de npm en script.

### atencion

para usar browserify tienes que instalar nodejs y npm :(, asi que quizas te conviene pasarlo a mano

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pides es muy facil, solamente tienes que cargar react en la cabecera asi:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router/umd/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>
```

Y automáticamente ya tienes todos los comandos de `React` como funciones, ya no tienes que importar nada

por ejm:

```
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
```

Para acceder a cada función solamente revisas:

```
window.React
window.ReactRouterDOM
window.ReactRouter
```

Y lo único que queda por ahora es convertís JSX en JS usando el traductor en línea babel.

Y por ejemplo si el código que sale usa la función `Component`, le agregas `React.Component` por que ahora es parte del objeto `React` y lo mismo con lo demás